# Site switcher shows blank community name in Community Moderators Blog

Tags: bug, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, blog-overflow

In [Stack Exchange Community Moderator Blog](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/), the site switcher shows me...

[image: screenshot]

Well...have I strayed from Stack Exchange network?

Comment: Ha. That blog isn't really attached to a site... and it looks like I'm gonna have to dive back into PHP at some point and see what's going on here.

Comment: Make sure to wear protective clothing @AdamLear to prevent getting infected by the PHP virus...

Comment: @Adam no plans to move everything to the shiny new blog platform you built? (SE, not you personally ;-))

Comment: @ShadowWizard No. The maintenance (builds, repos, etc.) sounds like a nightmare. Also, how do you picture that working for non-technical sites? Even you post bug reports on meta instead of doing a pull request with fixes. ;) Wordpress isn't great, but the barrier of entry is a ways lower.

Comment: @Adam true, but still, having such a mix of languages and platforms sounds like a nightmare as well.